# If cell in column 8 equals cell in column 1 on another tab set a variable based on adjacent cell of column 1

Tags: google-apps-script

I am needing to write an apps script function if dropdown in column 8 of "Working" tab matches cell in column 1 of "Match" Tab then set a variable to equal the adjacent cell in column 2. I am trying to determine the email address of person in dropdown using match.

I have this so far

```
    function findDuplicate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Working'); 
  var vs1 = sh1.getRange('H1:H' + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Match'); 
  var vs2 = sh1.getRange('A1:A' + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  if (vs1 === vs2) {
    return vs2.offset(1,0)
  };
```

}

I know this isn't complete but unsure how to proceed.

Example sheet for clarification.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OKFoS17le-Y5SAOecoLE4EJxiKqKVjRLRHtMzwHNwxM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function findDuplicate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Working'); 
  var vs1 = sh1.getRange('H1:H' + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Match'); 
  var vs2 = sh1.getRange('A1:A' + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  for(let i = 0;i<(vs2.length -1) ;i++ ) {
    if(vs1[i] == vs2[i]) {
      return sh2.getRange(i + 2, 1).getValue()
    }
  }  
}
```